# Visual Basic Max function throwing 1004 error

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 table "PurposefulSample" and "scaled". This macro is being written for scaled.

Now when I run this one, it throws a 1004 at *rowMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(src.Cells(curRow, 11), src.Cells(curRow, 37)))*. 
Some cells in the given range are also strings. Few others are #N/A too.

Noob in VB. Really appreciate any help.

```
Sub stdInScaled()

Dim curCol, curRow
curRow = 2

Dim src As Worksheet
Set src = Worksheets("PurposefulSample")

Do While (src.Cells(curRow, 1).Value <> "")
curCol = 11

    Do While (CStr(src.Cells(curRow, curCol).Value) <> "")
        If (IsNumeric(src.Cells(curRow, curCol).Value)) Then
            Dim rowMax
            rowMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(src.Cells(curRow, 11), src.Cells(curRow, 37)))
            If (rowMax > 1) Then
                Cells(curRow, curCol).Value = 100 * CLng(src.Cells(curRow, curCol).Value) / rowMax
            Else
                Cells(curRow, curCol).Value = "No Business"
            End If
        Else
            Cells(curRow, curCol).Value = "Data NA"
        End If
        curCol = curCol + 1
    Loop

    curRow = curRow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: put `src.` in front of range also so `...WorksheetFunction.Max(src.Range(...`

Comment: You need to go through the entire code and any range object should have the parent sheet as a precedent.  There are many `Cells` without the sheet qualifier.

Comment: I was expecting that those cells without sheet qualifier will point to the current/active sheet.

Comment: Yes, it will but to be sure it is good practice to still put a qualifier.  If the sheet is dynamic then I would set a variable to the activesheet.  Then use that as the parent.  Just in case the active sheet changes while the code is running.

Comment: The real problem is the errors.  You will get an error returned on the max.  Can you deal with the error in the formulas so they return 0 instead of #N/A?

Comment: Cant change it to 0, because it has to denote unavailable data instead of a 0 score. I tried changing it to a 'string' but not helping. The inner parenthesis is showing "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed". Does that ring any bell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. It is always good practice to qualify the parentage of all range objects, just to ensure no mix up of which cell is being referenced.
2. With the chance of errors being in the data, an array formula Max will need to used to skip the errors.  Also on the formula lets move it up one loop so it does not recalc the same answer every column.

code:

```
Sub stdInScaled()

Dim curCol, curRow
curRow = 2

Dim src As Worksheet
Set src = Worksheets("PurposefulSample")

Dim trgt As Worksheet
Set trgt = Worksheets("scaled")

Do While (src.Cells(curRow, 1).Value <> "")
    curCol = 11
    Dim rowMax
    Dim rng As String: rng = src.Range(src.Cells(curRow, 11), src.Cells(curRow, 37)).Address
    rowMax = src.Evaluate("Max(IF(isnumber(" & rng & ")," & rng & "))")
    Do While (CStr(src.Cells(curRow, curCol).Value) <> "")
        If (IsNumeric(src.Cells(curRow, curCol).Value)) Then
            If (rowMax > 1) Then
                trgt.Cells(curRow, curCol).Value = 100 * CLng(src.Cells(curRow, curCol).Value) / rowMax
            Else
                trgt.Cells(curRow, curCol).Value = "No Business"
            End If
        Else
            trgt.Cells(curRow, curCol).Value = "Data NA"
        End If
        curCol = curCol + 1
    Loop
    curRow = curRow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Aah worked like a charm. Thanks a ton. Any good literature u want me to read on this?

Comment: I learned by trial and error as I did projects for my last job.  Most my references came from googling till I found an answer I could use and understand.